# Domain name is resolving to DC that is not accessable for VPN users

Tags: networking, vpn, domain, internal-dns

Problem is when one (and only one) VPN user tries to resolve our domain name (xxx.local), it is resolving to a DC that is not accessible to VPN users, and not the ones that are accessible.

We have 2 sites with a point-to-point connection between them and a DC for each. VPN comes in though site A. VPN traffic is not allowed from site A to site B. When one user tries to resolves our domain name though VPN, it is pointing to the DC in site B, instead of the one in site A. Typically, the domain name will point to the DC that is on the same subnet as the user. Each site is also on its own subnet.

I have tried forcing the domain name to point to the correct DC by editing the users host file and this did not help. Also have deployed the user a new computer and still have the same result.

Any insight as to why this might be?

Answer (score 2):

In Active Directory Sites and Services, you have to define a subnet for the VPN user, and assign it to the site that has the DCs you want them to talk to.